# Registering multiple objects with same interface in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I'm calling the below code in `XYZManager` class's constructor and the application is working.

```
var handlers = new ITableType[]
{
    new AbcHandler(new Logger(), new Repository()),
    new OtherHandler(new Logger(), new Repository())
    /*etc...*/
};
```

`XYZManager`, `Logger` and `Repository` are registered in my application using Autofac.

The problem is I will have around 25 handlers when I go live and so would like very much a way to have a more maintainable code...

I hope I have been able to explain my problem.

EDIT: What I would like to know is how to register my handlers in autofac and what changes do I need to make to my above code..

I guess I could register every handler like this :

`builder.RegisterType<AbcHandler>().As<ITableType>()`

But how do I change my XYZManager class's constructor

Comment: You may want to try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Paddy codereview stated:  asking for advice about code not yet written are off-topic, as the code is not ready for review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you register your implementors of `ITableType`, you can define your constructor like so...

```
public XYZManager(ITableType[] handlers, /* other params... */)
{

}
```

and Autofac will give you an array with one of each of your registered `ITableType` objects.

Comment: Could you please have a look at this question as well:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709577/scope-and-resolve-in-autofac Tx